# Unsupervised classification in ERDAS imagine

Tags: erdas-imagine, time, image-classification

I am trying to make a classification to run some index ( like NDVI) to see the change over time using the image difference function. Is it possible to do an unsupervised classification on one image and apply this classification scheme for the rest of the images in the time series? If there is a way, how?